# Как связать таблицу phpexcel с сервером

Tags: php, сервер, клиент-сервер, phpexcel

У меня есть таблица, написанная на phpexcel и она должна брать значения `general_power_pr`, `time_pr` ,`general_power_vt` , `time_vt`, `num_of_sys_pr` из базы данных. Как это сделать я не знаю.

```
<?php
//Запускаем сессию
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';

$Pritoch=0.6*general_power_pr*time_pr;
$Vuchyaz=0.15*general_power_vt*time_vt;
$kapvlozh=150*($num_of_sys_pr+$num_of_sys_vt);
// Создаем объект класса PHPExcel
$xls = new PHPExcel();
// Устанавливаем индекс активного листа
$xls->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
// Получаем активный лист
$sheet = $xls->getActiveSheet();
// Подписываем лист
$xls->getProperties()->setTitle("Таблица рассчётов");
$xls->getProperties()->setSubject("Математика");
$xls->getProperties()->setCreator("Ardalin");
$xls->getProperties()->setCreated("25.01.2021");

//===========Начало стиля ячеек==========//
$sheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Arial');
$sheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(11);
$border = array(
    'borders'=>array(
        'allborders' => array(
            'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_MEDIUM,
            'color' => array('rgb' => '000000')
        ),
    )
);

//=============Конец стилей для ячеек //

//============Заполнение ячеек==============//

$xls->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$sheet = $xls->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setTitle('Рассчёты');
$sheet->setCellValue("A1:A2", "Год");
$sheet->setCellVaule("B2:B12","=(($Pritoch+$Vuchyaz)*$price)");
$sheet->setCellValue("C2:C12","=$kapvlozh");
$sheet->setCellValue("D2:D12","=$kapvlozh*0.1");
?>
```